# CollectionCell data display question when using custom segmented control in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I made a custom segmented control with reference to  "http://bitly.kr/fDz2Ma". However, when I select a particular item, I need to see the collection view cell that matches the item, but I have not found the selected index of the segmented control.

I have created custom segmented controls to date but have not found the selected index button item.

```
import UIKit

class MainBookViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var interfaceSegmented: CustomSegmentedControl! {
    didSet{
        interfaceSegmented.setButtonTitles(buttonTitles: ["A","B","C"])
        interfaceSegmented.selectorViewColor = .red
        interfaceSegmented.selectorTextColor = .red
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    codeSegmentedConfig()
}

func codeSegmentedConfig() {
    let codeSegmented = CustomSegmentedControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 90, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50), buttonTitle: ["A","B","C""])
    codeSegmented.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.addSubview(codeSegmented)
}

}

extension MainBookViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView
        .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MainBookCell", for: indexPath) as! MainBookCell

        cell.bookTitleLabel.text = "apple"
        cell.bookWriterLabel.text = "me"
        cell.bookImageView.image = UIImage(named: "3")

        return cell
    }
}
```

If I only know the button index of the selected custom segmented control, I want to use the case statement to change the data in the collection view cell to the index number.

If I only know the index of the selected button item, I plan to modify the collection view cell using the case statement in the CollectionViewDataSource code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you could achieve that by doing something like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        switch interfaceSegmented.selectedSegmentIndex {
          case 0:
            //do something when selected segment index is 0
          case 1:
            //do something when selected segment index is 1
          default:
            break
    }
```

Comment: In the "switch interfaceSegmented.selectedIndex" code, I get an error "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value". There is currently no value for "interfaceSegmented.selectedIndex".

Comment: Please check that the IBOutlet is connected, because `selectedSegmentIndex` is not optional, the only optional value in that scope is `interfaceSegmented`